# How to change the glyph (small arrow) in a scrollbar?

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, scrollbar

How can I change in a wpf the glyph (small arrow, up and down) in size and color? I would like to use xaml and it can be static (no change while running).

Is it possible and if yes how can I apply the such style?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to edit the Data of the `RepeatButton`'s `Content` inside the `ScrollBar` [Style Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742173%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or place an image in their `Content` or whatever you want to do. A tip for customizing control templates would be to use Blend as it generally makes the task a bit easier but it's not as tough as it might sound.

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: I dont really get it... Lets say I have following code:

`code`<Style x:Key="ScrollBarButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
    etc...>


How can I apply this style to my Scrollbar now?
`code`<ScrollBar Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarButton}" Height="100" etc...

For some unknown reasons it does not work like this.
Thanks for the help

Comment: I would ask if this is something you're trying to do adhoc for a single instance, or trying to use globally as part of a theme? If it's the latter I would do it directly into the scrollbar template. I'm heading to bed in a minute so response will be delayed and I'm a bit tired to punch out an example and for the moment would just point you to one of many tutorials out there for [styling a scrollviewer/Scrollbar](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37366/Styling-A-ScrollViewer-Scrollbar-In-WPF)